# How to say 'finally' as in 'after waiting a long time'

Tags: english-to-japanese, style

How do I say 'finally' as in 'after waiting a long time' in a sentence? Do I use '最後に'?

> Hanako can finally buy the textbook.

> 花子さんは教科書を最後に買えます。

Or does 最後に only mean 'finally' as in 'last in sequence'

Comment: [Relevant question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12682/differences-between-%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%84%e3%82%88-%e3%82%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a8-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%82%84%e3%81%8f-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%86). The Japanese language makes this seemingly straightforward question a bit of a PITA to answer comprehensively, because it gives you so many options! Each with a slight difference in connotation...

Comment: 最後に sounds like "by/at the end", so maybe she wasn't able to afford a textbook until the last day of the class.  @Will 's "relevant question" is fantastically helpful if you check it out.

Answer (score 2):

@Will Thank you for this relevant link. とうとう seems to be what I'm looking for. [Differences between いよいよ / やっと / ようやく / ついに and とうとう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12682/differences-between-%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%84%e3%82%88-%e3%82%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a8-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%82%84%e3%81%8f-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%86)

Comment: What the linked question/answer fails to explain is that とうとう is primarily used with negative outcomes. For example, dying after losing a long battle with cancer. With positive outcomes, やっと is a better choice, or いよいよ/ようやく for more neutral/mixed cases.